# Manually Editing Shopify theme takes time

Tags: shopify-app, shopify-template

My app needs to edit existing element in liquid file of store.

There are two ways to edit liquid file of store :-

1. Manually (downloading theme files in local then make required changes and upload).
2. Write a script which changes theme files automatically whenever merchant install app on store.

Unfortunately we can't edit different theme with same script, because each theme might be very different. Some themes might even have different filenames for this sections or they might have completely different HTML structure.

I am new with the Shopify That's why I need to go through 1 option. But, I am concern about, Is it okay to say merchants that wait for xyz hours then the app functionality will be visible and is there any app does that ?

Any thoughts or insight will be helpful

Answer (score -1):

@yash Soni

Shopify has already given solution
https://shopify.dev/themes/tools/theme-kit